# React this.state.addroom.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

So I am trying to gen a div with a button onClick of a button but I get an error that is stopping me from doing this.

Error: `TypeError: this.state.addroom.map is not a function`

But I saw that when I click my button once it doesn't show the error but it doesn't generate the div with the button either.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Select, { components } from 'react-select';
import styles from '../styles/loginsignup.css'
import axios from 'axios'
import nextId from "react-id-generator";
export default class AccomodationInfo extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            accomcate: null,
            addroom: ['one'],
            isLoading: true,
        }
      }
     handleClick = event => {
        const htmlId = nextId()
        event.preventDefault()
        const addroom = this.state.addroom
        this.setState({ addroom: htmlId })
        return (   
            <div>

                {this.state.addroom.map(addrooms => (
                  <button key= {addroom.id} className={addrooms.modifier}>
                    {addrooms.context}
                  </button>
                ))}
           </div>   
          );
    }



    render() {
         return(
           <div>
           <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>
           </div>

        )


    }


}
}
```

Anyone knows what causes it and how we can fix it?

Comment: Your `handleClick` is not supposed to return jsx. That's not how it works. Check out examples in react docs https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things off with your code.

First of all the `addroom` in your state is a string array in your constructor, but in the `handleClick` method you set it like `this.setState({ addroom: htmlId })` which will set it to a `string` and on a `string` type the `map` function is not defined, hence the error.
You should add an item to the array like `this.setState({ addroom: [...this.state.addroom, htmlId] })`

Secondly, in your `handleClick` you shouldn't return jsx, if you wan to render data for your `addroom` array, you should do it in the `render` method, and in the `handleClick` you should just modify the `addroom` state variable.
You can achieve this like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add</button>
      {this.state.addroom.map((addroom) => (
        <button>{addroom}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Lastly, your `addrom` variable is a string array only, so you can't access `id`, `modifier` and `context` in an item in that array.

Comment: I understand first and the third thing you said and I don't get an error anymore but how will I do the second one?

Comment: I have modified the corresponding part of the answer with an example